# Is it possible to increase horizontal space between characters in the text field?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a *captcha* field, and I like to increase the empty space between the characters, Here is current shape: *(I know the white space between characters is depends to the font, but I want to know there is another approach for increasing it or not)*

[image]

Now I want something like this:

[image]

It should be noted I can do that using a jquery code *(add a space after inserting each character)*, But actually I don't want `<space>`, I want a empty space between characters. I mean is if somebody select the value of that text field and then copy it and then past somewhare, I want to he see it as a series of concrete numbers like this: `65669`

Well, there is any solution?

Comment: You have a captcha with plain text? It will be trivial to bypass by bots, but annoy your users.

Comment: @Oriol what?! the left box is not plain text, it is a photo. a bot can bypass it?! and user should enter the numbers in the left photo in the right text field

Comment: Ah, OK. I though you wanted to use CSS to style the captcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `letter-spacing` CSS property to achieve this. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/letter-spacing) for more information.

```css
.wide {
  letter-spacing: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span>Normal spacing</span>
<br />
<span class="wide">Wide spacing</span>
```

Comment: Very good, `letter-spacing` is exactly what I wanted. Thanks. +1 upvote for you.